# Mobile Landing go back no redirection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a web page that redirects to a mobile land page. It works, but on the mobile land page I want to go to the main page without using redirection but, of course, each time I go to the main page, it redirects me to the mobile land page (of course, as the script runs...).

So my question is: how can I link the mobile land page to the main page without redirecting when I link to it?

Comment: Can you post your Script or refer it with some example...just to get some more clear understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a parameter on the url to the main page on the mobile site eg:

```
<a href="mainpage.html?mredirect=false">Go to full site</a>
```

Then on the main page  check if the parameter exists before redirecting.

```
var mredirect = getParameterByName("mredirect");
if(!mredirect && isMobile){
  //redirect to mobile site
}
```

**getParameterByName** : [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Thanks Richard. I was thinking on that, but wanted to ensure ;)